# Laravel @yield is undefined for HTML section

Tags: php, laravel

The layout/template file is defined in `footer.blade.php`:

```xml
@extends('mainpage')

@section('footer')

<section class="section5">
    <footer class="container col-lg-12 pb-2 pt-4">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Features</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">FAQs</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="row">
            <p class="small-text col-lg-3 text-lg-start text-center">© MyCompany.com @php echo date("Y") @endphp </p>
            <p class="small-text col-lg-6 text-lg-center text-center">All trademarks used on this site are the property of their respective owners.</p>
            <p class="small-text col-lg-3 text-lg-end text-center">Terms & Conditions | Privacy Policy</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>

@endsection
```

This is then yielded in `mainpage.blade.php`:

```xml
    <!-- REST OF HTML -->
    @yield('footer', 'Undefined')
</body>
```

Both files exist in the same directory, and there is also a route for `/mainpage` defined in web.php:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return View::make('mainpage')->render();
});
```

Yet the only thing that navigating to `/mainpage` shows me is the Undefined "error" that I passed to it as the second argument to the `@yield` helper. Inspecting in the browser shows that the section isn't loaded.

Because the template inheritance fails silently without an error and because Laravel apparently doesn't even have an intuitive way of printing warnings, such a basic use case seems impossible for me to debug.

What's going on here, or alternatively, how would I begin to go about debugging it?

Comment: you are returning `mainpage` ... where would it get the data for the `footer` section from? seems like you want `mainpage` to be the template that another view would extend from

Comment: @lagbox isn't that the purpose of `@extends('mainpage')` and `@yield('footer')`?

Comment: but you are returning `mainpage` ... you would have to return a view that extends `mainpage` and also there is nothing including that footer

Comment: @lagbox So you're saying that I need both a third view and an `@include` statement? I based my code on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#layouts-using-template-inheritance) which mentions only a layout view and a child view, and absolutely nothing about includes.

Comment: what is the child view? `footer`? if that is the case then return `footer` as the view .. you are returning the layout as a view for some reason

Comment: @lagbox I see. How would I set it up if I wanted to load the 'mainpage' as the route for obvious reasons, and have sections like the footer defined in their own files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current view to work, your route would need to call `footer` instead of `mainpage`.

`footer.blade.php` *knows* what view it extends.

```xml
<!-- footer.blade.php -->
@extends('mainpage')   <!-- Ok, extend mainpage.blade.php -->

@section('footer')  <!-- place this section where there's a @yield('footer') in mainpage.blade.php -->
@endsection
```

`mainpage.blade.php` ***doesn't know*** what views will extend it.

```xml
<!-- mainpage.blade.php -->
@yield('footer', 'Undefined') <!-- Place 'Undefined' if the views that extend me don't have a @section('footer') -->
```

I could make a second view called `footer2.blade.php`, and also have it extend `mainpage`. In that situation, which view should `mainpage` render?

---

What you want for generic sections like footers is [including a subview (using @include)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews).

Here's a crude example:

```xml
<!-- layout-1.blade.php. This layout has a navbar, sidebar and footer. -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- layout-1 navbar -->
    @include('navbar') 
    <!-- layout-1 sidebar -->
    @include('sidebar')
    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>
    <!-- layout-1 footer -->
    @include('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

```xml
<!-- layout-2.blade.php. This layout has a navbar and a footer but no sidebar -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- layout-2 navbar -->
    @include('navbar')
    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>
    <!-- layout-2 footer -->
    @include('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

```xml
@extends('layout-1')

@section('content')
@endsection
```

```xml
@extends('layout-2')

@section('content')
@endsection
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I see what you're saying now, I had completely misunderstood what `include` was for. Thank you for the detailed answer.